# MongoDB index creation goes past 100% and appears to loop forever

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a MongoDB collection with ~5.5M records. My attempts to index it, whether on a single field or with a compoundIndex fail as the indexing process proceeds normally but then when it reaches 100% where I presume it should stop, it goes past 100% and just continues on. I've left it running for 10 hours but it never ended.

The fields I try to index on are longs or doubles.

I'm running the latest MongoDB version on x64 Windows.

Am I right to think that this is abnormal behaviour? Any ideas what I can do?

```
Wed Sep 05 10:22:37 [conn1]             415000000/5576219       7442%
Wed Sep 05 10:22:48 [conn1]             417000000/5576219       7478%
Wed Sep 05 10:22:59 [conn1]             419000000/5576219       7514%
```

Comment: Ha, that's funny. Never seen it before :)

Comment: What version do you have? Is this server getting a lot of inserts?  This could be that index is still being created as more data is inserted.

Comment: db version v2.2.0, pdfile version 4.5.

No, there are no inserts whatsoever at this time. Just the indexing process.

Comment: Anything weird showing in the logs? is the mongo process using a lot of CPU?

Comment: No, however it does like to eat all available memory which makes all my other applications (e.g., Eclipse) really slow. However, my searches seem to indicate that is to be considered normal.

Comment: I built an index on 5 million documents `for (var i=0; i<5000000; i++) { db.coll.insert({num: NumberLong(i)}) }` and it took 16 seconds on this index `db.coll.ensureIndex({name:1})`.
I tried on v2.1.2 - Windows 7 64bit. I'll try 2.2.0 tomorrow.

Comment: Not sure what else could be the cause of this. I've installed 2.2.0 , dropped the index and created them again and it took tens of seconds again. How big are your documents?

Comment: About 1kb each perhaps. That being said, I got some help on MongoDB google group, which said my DB was probably corrupted in some HDD crash and I should reexport and reimport all data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per helpful advice from mongodb-users list:

This was likely due to running out of disk space and getting the database corrupted due to that.

What I did is I cleared up disk space, then ran "mongodump --repair" and then "mongorestore".

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing! i just had the same issue (External Sort Progress: 3252591449/454490 715657%) you described and even "mongod --repair" did not work (endless loop). Very, very annoying, but at least it works ...

Comment: Yes, harald, "mongod --repair" didn't help in my case too.